# How do I get a volume OSD just like the one in OSX?

Tags: linux, audio, arch-linux, alsa, osd

I'm using a Dell Studio laptop which has volume up/down hotkeys. On pressing these, I want a volume OSD to popup to show my current volume status just like in OSX; that is, just like:

[image: OSX Volume]

Anybody know any solution that would work on Arch Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, people don't read what others say. If you said Linux, that certainly doesn't mean Windows :)

Try this interesting project:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=132218
Volnoti is not so straight forward as those windows candies, but arch linux folks are amazing in terms of help - so, on that forum thread, you'll find all instructions, and configuration scripts that need to be written in order to have this running.

good luck

Comment: Aha! This seems quite useful. Many thanks! At least I have access to the source in case I'm not happy with it.

Answer (score -2):

Also you can look  [Volume²](http://irzyxa.deviantart.com/art/Volume2-version-1-1-3-247-Release-340146840)

> Volume² is an advanced Windows volume control, a complete replacement for the standard Volume Control. This application lets you easily change the sound volume just by rotating the mouse wheel or by using keyboard hot keys or just mouse move on screen border. It includes an audio mixer with advanced volume controls support, a scheduler, an on-screen display, command line support, the ability to store and recall different unlimited presets via one mouse click or system-wide hot keys. Support many languages such as: English, Russian, Greek, Armenian, Bulgarian, Ukrainian, Belorussian, German, Serbian, Portuguese, Armenian, Spanish, Japanese, Swedish, Slovak, French, Italian, Latvian, Polish, Hungarian, Chines(trad), Chines(sim), Arabic.

Comment: I guess I must be more specific. I want something that works on Arch Linux. From the link, it looks like it works on Windows only! I thought the tags in my question implied this, but oh well.